# Horizontal scroll with prev & next button in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular6

I am using angular 6 and Bootstrap 4 I'm trying to get horizontal ng-for loop with prev & next button feature.

It will be look like below,

[image]

I have no idea to achieve this. Can you please give me some suggestion or any angular library is available which can help me out to get this.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: Take a look at fxFlex for Angular. That might be helpful in getting the horizontal scrolling

Comment: Thanks @LingVu, Am using bootstrap 4. So anything in that ?

Comment: Welcome Basha, do you want to scroll chapters content (not shown in your screenshot), the menu (titles) or both? If you have set an horizontal scroll area with many elements outside of your visible region, you can move your scroll automatic with your prev & next button using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout